# Perl: Find first hash key of one hash that's also in another hash

Tags: perl, hash

I wrote this simple sub and it works as sold:

```
sub search_dispatch_table
{
    my ($href1, $href2) = @_;

    foreach my $key (keys %$href1)
    {
        return $key if exists $href2->{$key};
    }
    return undef;
}
```

I simply want to return the first key of `href1` which also exists in `href2`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean "first" as in "any key will do, just stop when you find one" or as in "the first key when sorted in some order"? (Your code does the former, but just want to make sure.)

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: You didn't specify the criteria you wish to use to evaluate which solution is better.

Comment: Also, what's better may be in the context -- what is this for, how is it used?

Comment: I mean by first that any key would do, because I know that the keys in both hashes would be unique. And by "better" I also meant if there's any CPAN module that does same? thanks

Comment: There is a nice `List::Compare` module, which you can initialize in very specific ways for speed, and (also) by _hash_ references. (From this machine I could only post untested, what I don't like.)  But using this is an overkill if you literally only want to do what the question states -- your code is more to the point and more efficient, thus better for the purpose.  And better yet with ikegami's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the criteria you wish to use to evaluate which solution is better.

Assuming you meant "faster", you can speed up the best case by using `each` instead of `keys`, but that's about it.

```
sub search_dispatch_table {
    my ($href1, $href2) = @_;

    while (my ($key) = each(%$href1)) {
        if (exists($href2->{$key})) {
           keys(%$href1);  # Reset iterator.
           return $key;
        }
    }

    return undef;
}
```

Comment: `# Reset iterator` nice! I've never used keys this way and you imply somehow that keys does something to `%$href1`, is that so?

Comment: Try `perl -E'my %h = map { $_= > 1 } qw( a b c d ); each(%h) for 1..2; say keys(%h);'` See the problem?